# Jquery problema ao ajustar janela do browser

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

![inserir a descrição da imagem aqui][1]Estou a desenvolver um website e estou com um problema ao ajustar a janela.
O problema é no menu do site(nav), quando estou a ajustar a janela para menor chega a um ponto em que o texto do menu desaparece.
O problema está no jquery 1.8.0.min porque quando retiro o include da página posso ajustar à vontade que nao afeta nada.
Quero que o site seja não responsive.

Comment: Diogo sem colocar o seu código não dá para saber qual o problema... Têm o site online? pode colocar o CSS, HTML e JavaScript relevantes ao problema?

Comment: Inflizmente ainda não está online.

Comment: Exemplo do menu:  a | b | c | d | quando está a janela do browser normal. Depois ao ajustar a janela para menor para meter até janela lado a lado com outro o menu a| b| c| d não aparece só aparece o cabeçalho(nav).

Comment: Tem de fazer [edit] na pergunta para acrescentar HTML. Se a formatação estiver errada nós ajudamos. Pode também juntar um jsFiddle para recriar o problema num ambiente onde podemos testar.

Comment: Boa, estou a ver a imagem. Pode colocar o codigo (HTML, JS, CSS) em texto também no corpo da pergunta?

Comment: O java script é o jquery 1.8.0.min.js

Comment: Näo tem mais código JavaScript dentro da página que o jQuery 1.8? ok, então coloque só o HTML e CSS desse menu.

Comment: Eu quero é saber em que parte desse js se encontra a função que permite ajustar a janela sem alterar o conteudo do site

Comment: Diogo, se você só carrega a biblioteca do jQuery e não tem mais JavaScript/jQuery no seu site então o jQuery sozinho não faz nada. É o mesmo que lá não estivesse. Daí eu pedir o seu HTML e CSS para lhe poder explicar o problema e dar exemplos.

Comment: Ok Diogo, agora está a faltar o CSS. Por enquanto só vejo isto da sua página: http://jsfiddle.net/nndc0d75/

Comment: Sergio, veja o site online tive a metelo oleola.comuf.com

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Ok, então no seu site tem para alem do jQuery dois ficheiros. Um chamados `functions.js` onde tem algum código para caso de resize da janela e outro do "jQuery FlexSlider".

Para além disso tem imagens laterais com `position: absolute;` que vão inevitavelmente sobrepôr-se ao texto... O ficheiro de CSS também é bem grande: http://oleola.comuf.com/css/style.css

**Acho melhor começar uma página nova para aprender passo-a-passo...**

De qq maneira e para responder à sua pergunta, dentro de `functions.js` existe uma função chamada em várias partes do código, a função `mobile()`. Nessa função ele esconde os `ul` do menu se a largura do ecrã fôr inferior a 750px com `$('#navigation ul').hide()`.

A função em questão é:

```
function mobile() {
    var winW = $(window).width();
    if (winW > 750) {
        $('#navigation ul').show()  
    }else{
        $('#navigation ul').hide()
        $('#navigation a.nav-btn span.arr').removeClass('active');
    }
}
```

Se não souber como remover essa função do seu código sem gerar erros, sugiro usar somente:

```
function mobile() {
    return false;
}
```

Mas volto a dizer que devia começar do inicio, para aprender passo-a-passo.

Comment: Funcionou perfeitamente obrigado, será que me poderia ajudar a fixar as imagens na lateral?

Comment: @Diogo ajudo/ajudamos sim. Faca uma nova pergunta e explique o que está a acontecer e o que queria que acontecesse. Lembre-se que já há muito conteúdo aqui no site que pode resolver o seu problema. Dê uma olhada. Se não encontrar faça nova pergunta.